# Memory leak or consumption issues of a process in an embedded system

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory

If we want to debug memory-related issues of a process then we have to start the process using Valgrind. Are there any other tools using which we can analyze a process that is already running in the embedded system?
For example, a process will be started by the embedded system on bootup. The memory consumption of the process is increasing gradually. I don't want to kill and start the process with Valgrind, I want to inspect the existing process. Are there any tools that can help here?
I think we can try with `/proc/pid/maps`, but not sure how we can understand the anonymous allocations in `/proc/pid/maps` file.

Comment: Given that you have /proc/pid/maps, am I correct that your embedded system is running Linux?  If so, are you able to gather a live core of your already running process, for example by using **gcore**?

Comment: @TimBoddy How I can build `gcore` for an embedded device. I am using `Intel Atom` based platform and build system is `buildroot`. I didn't find any gcore package in buildroot  config.

Comment: Given that /proc/*pid*/maps is a Linux thing I was assuming that your embedded system was running Linux, is that not the case?

Comment: @TimBoddy yes, it is running with Linux. There are many entries with pathname entry as empty in /proc/*pid*/maps, how we can analyze these anonymous entries in /proc/*pid*/maps.

Comment: It is better to use a core file if you can, but first you need to figure out whether you can obtain one.  Gathering a core does not actually require gcore, because gcore is basically a wrapper around gdb, but it does require that you have gdb and can attach gdb to a running process, as in "gdb -p *process-id*".